# Allow "ObjectCreated" event notification from my zappa app

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm creating a [zappa app](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa#zappa---serverless-python) so I can perform a lambda function when an object is created in my S3 bucket. At the moment, when trying to update my zappa app via `zappa update dev` I get this error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetBucketNotification operation: Access Denied
```

I've [configured my AWS credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-config-files.html) on my Mac system so I assume the error is from my Bucket policy not allowing this event notification.

Here's my bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow All",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::****-bucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Deny All Actions On All But Media and Static Unless Defined User",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotPrincipal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::***********:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "NotResource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::****-bucket/media/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::****-bucket/static/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::****-bucket/media_thumbnail/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Any my CORS config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Here is my `zappa_settings.json`:

```
{
    "dev": {
        "aws_region": "us-east-2",
        "django_settings": "zappatest.settings",
        "profile_name": "default",
        "project_name": "zappatest",
        "runtime": "python3.6",
        "s3_bucket": "zappa-*******",
        "vpc_config" : {
            "SubnetIds": [ "subnet-******", "subnet-*******", "subnet-*******" ],
            "SecurityGroupIds": [ "sg-******" ] 
        },
        "events": [{
            "function": "zappatest.lambda_function",
            "event_source": {
                  "arn":  "arn:aws:s3:::*****-bucket/media/",
                  "events": [
                    "s3:ObjectCreated:*"
                  ]
               }
            }]
    }
}
```

Is the error because of my bucket policy security or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `s3:GetBucketNotification` permission to your bucket policy for your Zappa user:

```
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetBucketNotification",
        "s3:PutBucketNotification"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::*****-bucket"
      ]
    }
```

Those are *bucket* permissions. Double check that they are on the bucket:
`*****-bucket` and not on specific objects `*****-bucket/*`.